# Retornar ultimo ID UPDATE WITH JOIN SQL / PHP

Tags: php, sql, update, autoincremento, id

Buen dia,

Estoy tratando de retornar el ID de mi ultimo registro actualizado, para ellos uso -mysqli::$insert_id- .
el problema es que me retorna 0 como si no tuviera un campo AUTO_inc y si lo tengo
mi código es

```
$mysql = "UPDATE jobduties AS t1 LEFT JOIN  route AS t2 ON t1.codeRoute = t2.codeRoute SET t1.checkIn = ? , t1.idJobDuties = (SELECT @update_id := t1.idJobDuties) ";
$mysql .= "WHERE t1.codeStore = ? AND t1.dateDutie = ? AND t2.uppa =  ? ; ";
$tPr = 'ssss';
$vPr = [
    $checkIn,
    $codeStore,
    $dateDutie,
    $idUser
];
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($mysql);
$stmt->bind_param($tPr, ...$vPr);
$stmt->execute();
/// AMBSAS TABLAS TIENEN UN CAMPO AUTO_INCREMENT
 $idDutie = $conn->insert_id;
```

Lo que necesito es recuperar el ID de la tabla 't1', EL UPDATE funciona sin problema.

Agradezco de su apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca va a funcionar. Ya que el UPDATE no genera un nuevo autonumerico, a menos que tengas TRIGGERS u otra cosa por detras que afecten a nuevos registros.

Es logico que te devuelva 0, ya que no estás generando un nuevo ID.

Comment: La documentacion de PHP dice :
La función mysqli_insert_id() devuelve el ID generado por una consulta en una tabla con una columna que tenga el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT. Si la última consulta no fue una sentencia INSERT o UPDATE o si la tabla modificada no tiene una columna con el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT, está función devolverá cero.
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: UPDATE no genera un nuevo ID como lo hace INSERT, estamos hablando de 2 instrucciones completamente diferentes.